# Ingress with nginx ingress controller not works when I put 2 paths

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm a beginner with K8s, and I'm testing multiple scenarios, so I've got the next problem:

**When I apply an Ingress with 2 paths, the server response 404 for every URI**

This is my ingress YAML file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: pruebas
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: parking.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: front
          servicePort: 80
        path: /front
      - backend:
          serviceName: back
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

I've done several tests and these were the results:

- Only 1 path with "/" for "front": Works ✅
- Only 1 path with "/" for "back": Works ✅
- Only 1 path for "front" with "/front": Not works ❌
- Only 1 path for "front" with "/backend": Not works ❌
- 2 paths for "front" and "back" (the YAML file above) : Not works ❌

Api Service YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: back
  namespace: pruebas
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    type: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

**Additional info:** I made a test creating 2 services for hello-world of Nginx, I made the same that I said before and It works fine, So, I'm guessing I have a problem with my services or my pods, but I don't know what it could be.

**More additional info** It's running on GCP with GKE.

**Updated** I put this (*nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=back rewrite=/"*) and the route for API works, but not for the child routes (api/whatever)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: pruebas
  annotations:
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=back rewrite=/"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: parking.io
    http:
      paths:
      # - backend:
      #     serviceName: front
      #     servicePort: 80
      #   path: /app
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /hello
      - backend:
          serviceName: back
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

All the info inside my namespace "pruebas":

[image]

Comment: It might be many causes. What environment are you using? Minikube, kubeadm, cloud? Can you share your services? How are you testing if this works, curl?

Comment: Your current ingress configuration will match path 1:1 only. If you wants to match it with /api/something you should use this syntax: `/something(/|$)(.*)`. More details you can find [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

Comment: Did you deployed Nginx Ingress or you just created Ingress deployment?

Comment: @PjoterS, yes I installed the Nginx Controller with Helm, and then I created the ingress File. And responding to your first comment, I did it, I used that syntax but not works. My doubt is why when I put the nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=back rewrite=/" works and when I use "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target" not works

Comment: It would be possible to share your deployment and services? There might be typo in configuration. Also could you try to use images helloworld v1 and helloworld v2?

Comment: Thank you @PjoterS, I made some changes in my files, ingress controller, and ingress and all is running ok. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem by making these changes:

- Uninstall my ingress controller, and then remove the services, pods, and all related to it.
- I had my ingress controller on a different namespace (infra), So, I installed again the NGINX ingress controller in the same namespace of my services and pods (pruebas)
- I configured my ingress in the same namespace as the other pods, services, etc.

My cluster was configured on GKE, So, I don't know if this solution applies to different services.